# Filter collection with not?

Tags: powershell

I have a collection with data like this:

```
server : ExchangeServer
drive : C:

server : ExchangeServer
drive : R:

server : DomainController
drive : C:

server : AnOtherServer
drive : C:
```

What I would like is to exclude and servers called ExchangeServer with Drive R: from the collection.

I have tried:

```
$PerfCollection | Where-Object -FilterScript {
  $_.drive –eq "R:" -and $_.server -like "*ExchangeServer*"
}
```

but the collection end up just a list of Exchange servers with R: drives?

Is there a "not" option to `Where-Object`?

Comment: @mjolinor That alone doesn't suffice. You must also change `-and` to `-or`, otherwise it would exclude Exchange servers without a drive `R:` or servers with a drive `R:` that aren't Exchange servers too. `!(A ^ B) <=> !A v !B`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current condition *selects* elements that are Exchange servers and have a drive `R:`. To *exclude* Exchange servers that have a drive `R:` you need to invert that condition:

```
$PerfCollection | Where-Object -FilterScript {
  -not ($_.drive –eq "R:" -and $_.server -like "*ExchangeServer*")
}
```